# Creating Table in Angular Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a table using reactive forms in Angular Material. The problem is how can i implement a functionality that when you click the button "add row", it will automatically add a row, where you can input on a field.

[Please see this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-add-row-add-row?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

```js
createForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    products: this.fb.array([]),
  });
}

addRow() {
  const rows = this.form.get('products') as FormArray;
  rows.push(
    this.fb.group({
      product_id: [null],
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make it as follow

1. inputs in FormArray should have unique id
2. data-table needs trackBy to avoid row manipulation bug
3. to update data-table use table.renderRows();

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-ngform-input?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

```js
    <form [formGroup]="form">

      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <mat-table
          #table
          class="mat-elevation-z0"
          [dataSource]="dataSource" [trackBy]="trackRows">

          <!-- Product Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="product">
            <!-- <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Product</mat-header-cell> -->
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"> 
              <ng-container [formGroup]="row">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Product"
                    id="product_id_{{i}}"
                    name="product_id_{{i}}"
                    formControlName="product_id" required />
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Unit Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="unit">
            <!-- <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Unit</mat-header-cell> -->
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"> 
              <ng-container [formGroup]="row">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Unit</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Unit"
                    id="unit_{{i}}"
                    name="unit_{{i}}"
                    formControlName="unit" required />
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Header Declarations -->
          <!-- 
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          -->

          <!-- Row Declarations -->
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>

        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
            (click)="createRow()">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            Add New
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>

      </mat-card>
    </form>

    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

    @Component({
      selector: 'table-basic-example',
      styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
      templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
    })
    export class TableBasicExample {
      form: FormGroup;
      private formSubmitAttempt: boolean;
      private uid = 0;

      @ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<any>;

      displayedColumns = ['product', 'unit'];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<AbstractControl>;

      get productControlArray() {
        return this.form.get('products') as FormArray;
      }

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.createForm();
        this.addRow();
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(
          this.productControlArray.controls);
      }

      createForm() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          products: this.fb.array([]),
        });
      }

      trackRows(index: number, row: AbstractControl) {
        return row.value.uid;
      }

      private addRow() {
        const rows = this.productControlArray;
        rows.push(
          this.fb.group({
            uid: this.nextUid(),
            product_id: [undefined, Validators.required],
            unit: [0, Validators.required]
          })
        );
      }

      createRow() {
        this.addRow();
        this.table.renderRows();
      }

      private nextUid() {
        ++this.uid
        return this.uid;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Great work. But can you do on a table with columns?  I have to add may fields from there thats why. Thanks

Comment: @Robert you can add many columns into `displayedColumns` and template for each column should be provided as `Product Column`

Comment: Can you add a Unit column as input there? and also can you remove the <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Product</mat-header-cell>

Comment: @Robert i update example to remove header need to remove `mat-header-row`

Comment: @Robert `Unit` column it is pretty same template as `Product `

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this where i don't neat to repeat the code in the html like in the Unit and Product? Thank you

Comment: @Robert you can try wrap column definition into next `ng-container *ngFor` but bind all internals looks complicated